# Amazon Web Services secret key & id not being found in my bash profile when pushing cloned Rails 4 S3 app to Heroku

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I have an application I built that pushes images to Amazon S3 using Carrierwave. I forked and cloned that repo on Github. When trying to push it as a new application to Heroku, Heroku keeps throwing an error that it can't find my Amazon S3 secret key and ID and aborts the push. I have the original Secret Key and ID in my bash profile and pushing to heroku worked with that setup. I can't figure out why it isn't working with my clone of the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set configuration varibles via `heroku config:set KEY=VALUE` for them to be available on Heroku

Read more at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars